# Windows 10, IIS on port 80, System and compressed memory

Tags: windows-10, iis

I noticed that my Windows 10 PC has an IIS server listening on port 80.

One of the response headers is `Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0`

Fetching it via HTTP results in a
`Request Method: GET`
`Status Code: 404 Not Found`

When I check the PID via netstat, I get told that it is the same process which is listed as `System and compressed memory` in the Task Manager. Checking the properties I get told that this service is being served by `ntoskrnl.exe`

Why on earth is Windows 10 hosting a HTTP server? This is a direct upgrade form Windows 7 Pro, which never made use of IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No version of Windows (except for special Web Server Editions) installs IIS by itself or comes with it installed.

Either you, someone else or another Software package that required it enabled it. An upgrade to Windows 10 does not install IIS either.

If you don't need it, use the `Windows Features` dialog to turn IIS off.

IIS uses a kernel mode driver to listen to http requests, all kernel mode drivers are part of the `System` process.

It may be difficult to find out how IIS ended up enabled on your Windows 10, but you can start looking at the `Setup` log under `Windows Logs` in `Event Viewer`

Comment: Thanks. There was some .NET Extensibility 4.6 stuff (something about TCP and named pipe activation) enabled under WWW Services.